# Use Single PeerConnection for two different plugins of janus (VideoRoom & AudioBridge) in one Android Activity - Android

Tags: android, webrtc, streaming, janus, peer-connection

**Prerequisite:**

- I have added VideoRoom functionality in one activity and it is working fine
- Then i added AudioBridge functionality in another activity and it also worked fine
- Then i went to add both the functionalities in one Activity. VideoRoom functionality called first so it worked fine. Then AudioBridge functionality calls to join audioRoom through AudioBridge, Here "ICE failed" happens with"hangup" janus event, but VideoRoom call working fine.
- I have 2 separate PeerConnections for both. If i commented out VideoRoom call, then Audio call connected and works fine.

**Required:**

I want is to make 2 calls simultaneously in the same activity (i-e VideoRoom call and AudioBridge audio call).

**Problem:**

But here i guess 2 PeerConnections with same Janus Server cannot work.

I want to make Single PeerConnection so i can use that for both Calls (VideoRoom & AudioBridge).

How i can do it?. Can you refer any example like this. I am unable to find one.

Because While creating PeerConnection for VideoRoom i am passing PeerConnectionParameters for VideoRoom. Clearly i cannot use that as i have to pass parameters for AudioBridge in that while connecting.

Thanks.